# Cannot embed a tag in JavaScript slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created slide gallery via custom jQuery code.

HTML:

```
<div id="backgrounds">
    <img src="img/site/myimg.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc" />
    <img src="img/site/myimg2.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc" />
    <img src="img/site/myim3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc" />
</div>
```

JS function:

```
function ChangeBackground(background, direction) {
    if (is_animating)
        return;
    is_animating = true;

    $background = $(background);
    $newItem = null;
    if (direction == -1) {
        $newItem = $background.prev();

        if ($newItem.length == 0) {
            $newItem = $("#backgrounds img").last();
        }
    } else {
        $newItem = $background.next();

        if ($newItem.length == 0) {
            $newItem = $("#backgrounds img").first();
        }
    }


    $background.fadeOut(300);
    $newItem.fadeIn(300, function () {
        $("#backgrounds img").removeClass("current");
        $newItem.addClass("current");
        is_animating = false;
    });

    $clone = $("div.item.current").clone();
    $clone.removeClass("current").addClass("new");
    $clone.find("h1").html($newItem.attr("alt"));
    $clone.find("h2").html($newItem.attr("data-title2"));
    $clone.find("p").html($newItem.attr("data-desc"));
    $clone.css({ display: "none" });

    $("div.item.current").after($clone);

    $("div.item.current").fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $clone.fadeIn(300, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("new").addClass("current");
    });
}
```

It's working perfect. data-desc is like slide caption. And I want, embed a tag in this caption.

So:

```
<img src="img/site/myim3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc <a href="#">My a tag</a> />
```

But doesn't work. When check codes by DevTools, I seen:

```
<img src="img/site/myimg3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My desc &lt;a href=" #"="" style="width: 1451px; height: 956.0029282576867px; margin-left: -725.5px; left: 50%;">
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Encode them as html-entities, in php you can do it with `htmlspeciachars` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by properly closing the `double quotes` and replacing the double quotes with `single quote` which was wrapped around `#`

```
<img src="img/site/myim3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc <a href='#'>My a tag</a>"/>
```

You can notice the improper syntax over [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HcfMJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `"` within your attribute value, which is ending the attribute. You need to escape `"` with `&quot;` within the attribute, like

```
<img src="img/site/myim3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="My Desc <a href=&quot;#&quot;>My a tag</a>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

to embed a tag, use `<embed src=#>` in the caption part of your code.
Also, when giving references within a tag, use single quotes `'` instead of `"` as this unnecessarily closes the attribute

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to do "view" in "view". I mean if you created some XML structure, and one element relates to another it must be done by linking, not by inputting one into another.

In your situation i would prefer make that code such like that:

```
<div id="backgrounds">
    <img src="img/site/myimg.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="section.custom-tag" />
    <img src="img/site/myimg2.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc="#bg-1" />
    <img src="img/site/myim3.jpg" alt="Sample" data-title2="My Subject" data-desc=".custom-class" />
</div>
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <section class="custom-tag">Custom <b>description</b> with any html within</section>
    <div id="bg-1">Here we go!</div>
    <span class="custom-class">Test</span>
</div>
```

Then you can simply get inner HTML using:

```
$($newItem.attr("data-desc")).html()
// Or if you want to fetch with container tag use: 
$($newItem.attr("data-desc")).clone().wrap("<a/>").parent().html();
```

Cause of such problems as yours lot of HTML slideshows are build like this:

```
div.slider
    div.item*3
        img[src="smth.jpg"]
        div.custom-tag>{Content}
```

(See Emmet [Zen] coding for deeper understanding)